# Can I run Imagemagick on windows shared hosting

Tags: c#, windows, imagemagick, shared-hosting

I have shard hosting like GoDaddy with Windows. I am writing in ASP.NET c#. Can I use it from c# on the shared hosting?

Comment: You can contact Godaddy support team and if they support it, then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get them to install Imagemagick, then yes.